# IPTABLES redirect specific wan traffic back to another address on wan

Tags: linux, iptables

What i am trying to achieve with iptables is setting a rule(s) that when a specific packet arrives from wan it gets redirected to a new address on wan.

Example:

Any UDP packet arriving on port 10000 gets redirected to 8.8.8.8:10000. This can be more specific, like it originates from ip 1.1.1.1 or destination lan ip is 192.168.1.1 if there is a requirement for the rule to work.

Is this possible? Been trying a couple of rules in chain PREROUTING and using DNAT but i'm honestly in the dark here...

Comment: Look for "port forward"

Comment: AFAIK port forward does not redirect the packet to new IP address like i asked.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding _is an application of network address translation (NAT) that redirects a communication request from one address and port number combination to another while the packets are traversing a network gateway, such as a router or firewall._  It is one way many devices are protected from direct access on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

One can do a DNAT rule:

```
iptables -I PREROUTING -p udp --sport 10000 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.100.100:10000
```

This will replace the destination address in the IP packet to `192.168.100.100`.

The problem is that if the changed destination does not use the forwarding machine as its gateway, bi-directional communication does not work.

An example:

Sense - 10.100.100.10 = original sender of packet
Forwarder - 192.168.120.1 = destination of packet
Final destination - 192.168.100.100 = redirected destination

1. Sender sends a packet to Forwarder:10000
2. Forwarder changes IP address in the packet to 192.168.100.100 (Final destination) and forwards packet
3. Final destination receives the packet
4. Final destination sends response packet to 10.100.100.10, since that is the packet source address.

Now, since Sender originally sent a packet to Forwarder, it doesn't expect a response packet from Final destination. Therefore the response packet is dropped.

So, the only way to get this work properly is to make sure that return path of the packets goes via the box doing DNAT.

Answer (score 0):

Check current iptables rules

`iptables -t nat -L -n -v`

Enable IP forwarding

`echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

`cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

Rules to forward PG traffic

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination new-master-ip:80`

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE`

Check iptables rules

`iptables -t nat -L -n -v`